# SKEmitterNode change particle speed to particles already emitted

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

Is it possible to change the speed of particles already emitted? SKEmitterNode has a particleSpeed property, but this only applies to particles that will be emitted in the future.

As an example, let's say we're building a spaceship simulator. Imagine a spaceship rendered above an a starfield. The starfield was created through a particle file, rendered using SKEmitterNode. The spaceship through this simulation never changes position. The SKEmitterNode is composed of particles that move at a constant speed of 10 in the negative x direction. To simulate the spaceship accelerating, it would be nice to have the ability to change the speed of particles that have already been emitted. As of right now, if the speed of the particles were to change, the particles already emitted will be going at a slower speed than the particles that are being emitted after the speed change.

One solution is to define a particle system that emits particles in a range of, for example, 100 x 100 with 0 speed and 0 acceleration. This particle system would be rendered with a low zPosition value to stay in the background. To simulate spaceship movement, the x position of the SKEmitterNode would change relative to the speed of the spaceship. More SKEmitterNodes are added off of the scene, then scroll into view as the older SKEmitterNodes roll off and are removed.

I've tested that solution and it works, but I was curious if anyone has a more elegant solution.

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible. From the documentation: "Particle sprites are privately owned by Sprite Kit—your game cannot access the generated sprites." - (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You're definitely right, but I was hoping SKEmitterNode (the owner of these particles) could have had some options for this type of thing. It makes these particle systems seem very limited in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create a second `SKEmitterNode` that has the same style with a faster speed. Then run an `SKAction` or `SKAction sequence` to transition between the 2.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way around is to add the particles to a separate layer (empty SKNode).

```
var particleLayer = SKNode()
self.addChild(particleLayer)

var flowEmitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "yourEmitter.sks")
emitter?.targetNode = particleLayer
```

Then you can change the particles speed by moving this layer with SKAction.

```
particleLayer.run(.move(by: CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 0), duration: 5.0))
```