# SKEmitterNode updating speed of particles already released

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skemitternode

Using `SKEmitterNode` in `SprikeKit`, is it possible to change the speed/alpha of particles after they are released?

What I'm looking for is a particle emitter that emits particles, those particles are static but after x amount of seconds, they start moving. Is this possible?

Comment: My solution to alter speed of already cerated particles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839325/skemitternode-change-particle-speed-to-particles-already-emitted/67045466#67045466

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the answer in swift before i saw the objective-c tag.. hope thats okay.

heres my particle file so you can try it yourself:
[DOWNLOAD](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4kzFbLmJr19Y3Y0SGFKcnBKQkk/view?usp=sharing)

```
let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "fire")
emitter.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)

let time = CGFloat(2)
emitter.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.waitForDuration(3),
    SKAction.customActionWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(time), actionBlock: {
        _, t in
        let timePercentage = t / time  // percentage of elapsed time
        let maxSpeed = CGFloat(200)
        emitter.particleSpeed = timePercentage * maxSpeed
    })

]))

self.addChild(emitter)
```

this code will allow you to animate your emitter's properties over time.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't modify the particles that have ALREADY been emitted.

Comment: I found out the answer. I need to use alphaSequence and scaleSequence : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476390/spritekit-trouble-with-particle-keyframe-sequence

Comment: it was your question (link above) whose's answer helped me out so thank you anyways!